# HasMany association on an associated (belongstomany through) Model

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0, has-many-through

I'm trying to make this thing work :

`Orders` belongsToMany `Products` through `ProductsOrders`

ProductsOrders has a composite key (order_id, product_id) - At this point, everything work perfectly.

What I would like is to add a new association (`ProductsOrders` hasMany `Extras`) because a product can have a couple of data (sauces, kaking style, drink, ...).

So I've created the `Extras` model with :

```
$this->belongsTo('Orders', [
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

And I added the following in the ProductsOrders model

```
 $this->hasMany("Extras", [
            'foreignKey' => [
                'order_id',
                'product_id'
            ],
            'bindingKey' => [
                'order_id',
                'product_id'
            ]
        ]);
```

When patching the Order Entity, it seems to be correct : (simplified version)

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Order) {
    'establishment_id' => (int) 1,
    'state_id' => (int) 20,
    'products' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

            'id' => (int) 32,
            'establishment_id' => (int) 1,
            'category_id' => (int) 11,
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\OrdersProduct) {

                'quantity' => (int) 4,
                'price' => (float) 9,
                'extras' => [
                    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Extra) {

                        'title' => 'Sauces',
                        'choice' => 'Mayonaise',
                        'price' => (float) 0,
                        '[new]' => true,
                        '[accessible]' => [
                            '*' => true
                        ],
                        '[dirty]' => [
                            'title' => true,
                            'choice' => true,
                            'price' => true
                        ],
                        '[original]' => [],
                        '[virtual]' => [],
                        '[errors]' => [],
                        '[invalid]' => [],
                        '[repository]' => 'Extras'
                    
                    }
                ],
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'quantity' => true,
                    'price' => true,
                    'tva' => true,
                    'extras' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'OrdersProducts'
            
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is, when saving (with success), there is no Extras data in table ... That's sad.

Where did I make a mistake ? Or is this still possible ?

Thanks in avdance

Comment: While I believe extras should be saved to ProductsOrders table, if entity is being created properly and only saving that is the problem, try specifiying the **associations** option with the call to save() function.
Because, it saves only one level of assciations by default and you want second level data to be saved.
Most like this - $ordersTable->save($order, ['associated' => ['ProductsOrders', 'ProductsOrders.Extras']]);
[ref](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations)

Comment: I tried with your example ( and with ["associated" => true], but neither oh the both options works. Only the extras data are not saved. I'm going to try in the following days with a clean DB because I've made too much change now.

Comment: Okay, then you should put all the extra data into ProductsOrders table and set them using [_joinData option](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-data-to-the-join-table) [This link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) would also help.